# Vs2017 Xamarin forms, running emulator. how do you change the image the camera sees to one you make?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, android-emulator

Vs2017 Xamarin forms, when running emulator. how do you change the image the camera sees to one a custom one?

I'm trying to test the Scandit barcode scanner and need to add a barcode to the image for it to scan.

[image]

Comment: Did you set both (front and back) camera on the emulator settings? if you set bot you should be able to use one camera or the other.

Comment: Yes I set both to emulated, but it shows the default image, I need to change that to an image of a bar code so that the scanner can scan it.

Comment: If you're using a notebook you can set the computer webcam as camera, but if you use the emulated that android provides you won't be able to test bar code, best option for you is to test on real device.

Comment: I'm not on a notebook, but I have a webcam set up on my computer that I wanted to use. when I changed the hw/camera/front to webcam0, I got an error message that eth device couldn't contact the cameras (from the scandit driver). I also set hw.camera to true, at there other steps I'm missing?